# Using "Decimal" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal-point

Can someone please explain what's happening below: (I use Python 3.3)

```
1. >>> Decimal("0.1") + Decimal("0.1") + Decimal("0.1") - Decimal("0.3")
       Decimal('0.0')

2. >>> Decimal(0.1) + Decimal(0.1) + Decimal(0.1) - Decimal(0.3)
       Decimal('2.775557561565156540423631668E-17')

3. >>> Decimal(0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 - 0.3)
       Decimal('5.5511151231257827021181583404541015625E-17')
```

I know it has to do with floating point limitation, I'd be glad if someone can explain why

- What has the `" "` got to do with the difference between example 1 and 2 above
- Why does 2 produce a difference answer from 3 given that both have no `" "`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a nutshell, neither `0.1` nor `0.3` can be represented exactly as `float`:

```
In [3]: '%.20f' % 0.1
Out[3]: '0.10000000000000000555'

In [4]: '%.20f' % 0.3
Out[4]: '0.29999999999999998890'
```

Consequently, when you use `0.1` or `0.3` to initialize `Decimal()`, the resulting value is *approximately* `0.1` or `0.3`.

Using strings (`"0.1"` or `"0.3"`) does not have this problem.

Finally, your second example produces a different result to your third example because, even though both involve implicit rounding, they involve rounding to a different number of decimal places.