# Comparing Python Decimals created from float and string

Tags: python, decimal

Can someone explain why the following three examples are not **all equal**?

```
ipdb> Decimal(71.60) == Decimal(71.60)
True
ipdb> Decimal('71.60') == Decimal('71.60')
True
ipdb> Decimal(71.60) == Decimal('71.60')
False
```

Is there a general 'correct' way to create `Decimal` objects in Python? (ie, as strings or as floats)

Comment: Another highly related question - [Using “Decimal” in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572101/using-decimal-in-python)

Comment: Related: [Python Decimal Module - Undesired Float-Like Output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529898/python-decimal-module-undesired-float-like-output/31529936)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Floating point numbers, what are used by default, are in base 2. 71.6 can't be accurately represented in base 2. (Think of numbers like 1/3 in base 10).

Because of this, they will be converted to be as many decimal places as the floating point can represent. Because the number 71.6 in base 2 would go on forever and you almost certainly don't have infinate memory to play with, the computer decides to represent it (well, is told to) in a fewer number of bits.

If you were to use a string instead, the program can use an algorithm to convert it exactly instead of starting from the dodgy rounded floating point number.

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(71.6)
Decimal('71.599999999999994315658113919198513031005859375')
```

Compared to

```
>>> decimal.Decimal("71.6")
Decimal('71.6')
```

However, if your number is representable exactly as a float, it is just as accurate as a string

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(71.5)
Decimal('71.5')
```

Comment: Another point to add here is that `Decimal(71.60)` is represented as 
`Decimal('71.599999999999994315658113919198513031005859375')` in Cpython. (Link to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) on this matter)

Comment: Could you illustrate with some examples? *"They will be converted to be more decimal places"* is woolly at best.

Comment: if you convert float to Decimal it will add the junk values like 71.599999999999994315658113919198513031005859375  so its better to convert it to string decimal.Decimal(str(71.5)) and do the exact comparison

Answer (score 4):

Normally `Decimal` is used to avoid the floating point precision problem. For example, the `float` literal `71.60` isn't mathematically `71.60`, but a number very close to it.

As a result, using `float` to initialize `Decimal` won't avoid the problem. In general, you should use strings to initialize `Decimal`.